# Jquery selector based on class name behaves differenty

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
 $( ".validate-1" ).length
```

gives me value 6

but

```
   $( "input[class~='validate-']" ).length
```

gives value 0.

whats wrong here?

Comment: Read [the jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-word-selector/). You're using the wrong selector.

Comment: Try with `$("input[class*='validate-']" ).length`

Comment: Don't use class or id attributes with counting variables in them. Use a common class and access the specific element by index or DOM traversal instead.

Answer (score 9):

http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-word-selector/

> Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value
>   containing a given word, delimited by spaces.

Which means that your class should be `validate- something`. If you want wildcard you should use `*=`.

More at http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/